# Applying style to jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am using free jqgrid (latest version)

What I saw from the demo was the grid is blue.

I have use this in my application, not sure whats missing but the grid comes out to be gray. I also applied  guiStyle: "bootstrap" but that also just changes little appearance and fonts but not color. Also in the search dialog box the controls are aligned to each other like they are all together. See image link below for all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Ex0.jpg

1. How can I change the color to default blue
2. How can I fix the search dialog controls
3. How can I apply any other custom style formatting to this.

THanks

--------------Updated------------------

```
 <link href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> (bootstrap 4.0.0) 
 <link href="~/lib/free-jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" /> (4.15.2)
 <link href="~/lib/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="~/lib/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 @section scripts{
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="~/lib/free-jqgrid/dist/modules/grid.base.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/free-jqgrid/dist/modules/grid.common.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/free-jqgrid/dist/modules/grid.formedit.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/free-jqgrid/dist/modules/grid.filter.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/free-jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/free-jqgrid/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
```

I am not applying/using any styling other than above css/js and as have added below:

```
  guiStyle: "bootstrap",
  iconSet: "fontAwesome",
```

Comment: Please provides the demo (or demos), which demonstrates which CSS and JavaScript files you includes and which options you use. Do you use only Bootstrap CSS (Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4), only jQuery UI CSS or both? If you use default Bootsrap CSS then the most colors are gray. You can easy change the colors or background color for almost any element of the grid, but you should exactly specify what you need. The statements like "How can I change the color to default blue" gives almost no information because you don't specify any exact element of the grid (data, column header, pager, ...).

Comment: have updated the ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to specify more exactly what you do (with the demo) and what you want to have.

Before answering on your question I want to remark, that you don't really need to use `jquery-ui.min.css` for jqGrid is you use `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`.

The CSS settings for Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 3 are different. If you use free jqGrid with Bootstrap 4 thenb you have to use `guiStyle: "bootstrap4"` instead of `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`. See https://jsfiddle.net/ovq05x0c/1/ as an example.

If you include `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` then you don't need to include `grid.base.js`, `grid.common.js`, `grid.formedit.js`, `grid.filter.js` and in any way you need to include `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` because it's part of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` or `grid.base.js`. The file `query-ui.min.js` isn't needed too if you don't use jQuery UI yourself.

The best practice is to load all CSS and JavaScript files from CDN instead of loading there from the local server. Local server could be good for local application only, but not for the side available from Internet. See [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) for more information about the usage of free jqGrid from CDN.

I'd recommend you to read [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap) as the starting point of using free jqGrid. It provides some examples of customizing the grid. For example, the CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap {
    border: 1px solid #003380;
}
```

changes the color of the border of the outer div of the grid, the CSS rule

```css
 .ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-caption {
    background-color: #e6f0ff;
}
```

changes the background color of the caption/title. One more CSS rule

```css
.ui-jqgrid.ui-jqgrid-bootstrap .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {
    background-color: #cce0ff;
}
```

changes the background color of the column headers. In the same way you can customize any other element of jqGrid. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/90qmjean/7/ is en example of changing some colors and font size in free jqGrid and select2, which you probably use too.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. I have made changes as per your suggestion and would work  on changing the styles. There is just one thing here. Earlier I had guiStyle: "bootstrap" and after changing to guiStyle: "bootstrap4" whenever I select a row the selected row color does not changes. If I change it back to just "bootstrap" I can see the selected row color change. I also tried adding .ui-jqgrid-btable .ui-state-highlight {
    background: yellow; } as per one of your post but that also makes no effect.

Comment: @aman: Please provide *always* the demo if you report a problem or a bug. I included https://jsfiddle.net/ovq05x0c/1/ demo in my answer, which uses `guiStyle: "bootstrap4"` with Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.2 and free jqGrid 4.15.2. I see no problem with selection of rows in the demo.

Comment: Sorry there was an issue at me end. Although I had updated my bootstrap to 4, it was still referencing 3. I had to delete cache, restart browsers etc. Also there is another think in my project we are using some dash-light css for styling side and top menu. If I use bootstrap 4 then it messes it up. But it works fine with bootstrap 3 which I am updated back to. Now with bootstrap 3 my grid works fine but its just that I have to write  guiStyle: "bootstrap" instead of  guiStyle: "bootstrap3". When I write bootstrap 3 again my page messes up.

Comment: @aman: There are exist no `guiStyle: "bootstrap3"` option in free jqGrid. You should not use any fantasy values. The property `guiStyle` can be `"jQueryUI"`, `"bootstrap"`, `"bootstrapPrimary"` or `"bootstrap4"` if you don't define your custom GUI style. See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L559-L565).

Comment: Why gui of jqgrid does not look professional? i mean look at devexpress / telerik datagrid etc. Can you work on something similar design?